# Change another div's background color on click of div with angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a component on the page which has following divs

```
<div style=" width:400; height:400; float:left">
 <div style="background-color:red; width:50%; height:50%; float:left">
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:blue; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:green; width:50%; height:50%; float:left">
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:orange; width:50%; height:50%; float:right">
 </div>
 </div>
```

I have another div on the same page as

```
<div class="eventBox eventBox__colorBar"></div>
```

When i click on any of the div above, i want to get the selected color and apply as a background-color for the 2nd div.

How to do with angular2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code

```
<div>      
    <div style="background-color:red; width:50%; height:50%;" (click)="readColor($event)"> XYZ</div>
    <div style="background-color:blue; width:50%; height:50%; float:right" (click)="readColor($event)">blue</div>
    <div style="background-color:green; width:50%; height:50%; float:left" (click)="readColor($event)">green</div>
    <div style="background-color:orange; width:50%; height:50%; float:right" (click)="readColor($event)">black</div></div></div>

    <div  [style.background-color]="color">some text here</div>
</div>
```

Typescript method

```
 readColor(value){
    this.color=value.srcElement.style['background-color'];
    console.log(value.srcElement.style['background-color']);
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/qo4DaTBiET2lhnTgGGCR?p=preview)**

Comment: @Sajeetharan welcome. bro. happy to help you guru jee. :)