# Get the width, height and offset of clicked div - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a template that creates a list of links using `*ngFor` and a separate div element that I want to change its location based on the currently active link.

Template:

```
<div #divHandle
    *ngFor="let link of links; let i = index"
    class="div-link"
    (click)="changeActiveLink(i)">
    <h2>{{link}}</h2>
</div>
<div
[@indexState]="activeLink"
id="highlighter"></div>
```

This results in a structure like so:

```
<div class="div-link">
  <div (click)="changeActiveLink(0)"><h2>Link 1</h2></div>
  <div (click)="changeActiveLink(1)"><h2>Link 2</h2></div>
  <div (click)="changeActiveLink(2)"><h2>Longer link 1</h2></div>
  <div (click)="changeActiveLink(3)"><h2>Longer link 2</h2></div>
</div>
<div id="highlighter"></div>
```

I want my highlighter div to get the width of `Link 1` when `activeLink = 0`. Similar to this plain js:

```
var High = document.getElementById('highlighter');
High.style.width = document.getElementsByClass('div-link')[0].children[activeLink].offsetWidth; //activeLink = 0
```

In my `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChildren, Directive, QueryList, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[class~=div-link]'})
@Directive({selector: '.div-link'}) // variant
@Directive({selector: '#divHandle'}) // variant
@Directive({selector: '[divHandle]'}) // variant
export class ChildDirective {
    constructor(elem: ElementRef){}
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    ...
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChildren(ChildDirective) childrenContent: QueryList<ChildDirective>;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        console.log(this.childrenContent);
    }
}
```

When I log the `childrenContent` I get a `QueryList` object, but it is empty, no elements to get info from.

I have tried several `@Directive` selectors and always my `QueryList` is empty.

Comment: hey dude did u see my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the $event property to handle the width, height, offset and so on. By using this method, a traditional javascript comes into play as below

HTML code will be as

```
<div *ngFor="let link of links;" class="div-link" 
             height="100px"
             width="30px"
             (click)="changeActiveLink($event)">
          <h2>{{link}}</h2>
</div>
<div height="height" width="width" id="highlighter">some text</div>
```

Handling the clicked element from above div element as

```
changeActiveLink(value){
    this.height=value.srcElement.parentElement.attributes['height'].value;
    this.width=value.srcElement.parentElement.attributes['width'].value;
    console.log(this.width);
    console.log(this.height); 
  }
```

Note: In the above example, the click event is on the **letter** so we will get the srcElement as `h2` so I am using the parentElement. In real time you can handle it with either ways having a if condition inside the method.

You can also console.log the clicked element and get more idea to achieve this.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/roze6jemFjzp1iOMPKmp)**

Comment: This does not seem to work, I can pass the event, and I am able to get `value.srcElement` which is `<h2>link</h2>`, and `value.srcElement.parentElement` which will be the `<div></div>` but I cannot get `attributes['width']` that is undefined, and `.value()` fails as well.

Comment: you need the height and width of the clicked div element ?

Comment: Correct, clicking on the div `(click)=changeActiveLink()` should get the clicked div's width and offsetLeft, which should be used to animate the `highlighter` div's `width` and `offsetLeft`.

Comment: did u see console.log() in that plunker? have a reference at this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429689/change-another-divs-background-color-on-click-of-div-with-angular2). Still if you need some clarity tell me I will explain

Comment: Yea, it works in plunker, however, you set a fixed width on the links, mine does not have that, each word is a different length and makes the div's have different widths as a result. If I had them all a fixed width, I could just change the highlights value based of a multiple of the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a handle on the element you want to mess with ..

```
<div #handle ..>
```

then in your component class you can access the component using the @ViewChild annotation.

Then in your ngOnViewInit you can do ..

```
ngOnViewInit() {
  viewChildEl.offsetLeft = 100;
}
```

Should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am already using animation to manage the look of my`highlighter` div, but I do not know how to get the width of the list of div's created by the *ngFor, the @ViewChild appears to be for a single element. I need something more like `getElementsByClass` to get an array of elements. So I can get the width of a child of this array using the `activeLink` which is the currently active index, 0, 1, 2, 3,....

Comment: You can use `ViewChildren()` but you need to add `#handle` to every element you want to receive. `ViewChild(ren)` can only query for template variable names or component/directive types. You can create a directive with a class selector that injects `ElementRef` to get all elements using `ViewChildren` for a class.