# Changing Element Width using directives Angular2

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular 2. I was trying to change width of an element using 'ElementRef' and 'Renderer' which does not seem to work.

```
import { Directive, Renderer, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myHighlight]'

})
export class myDir {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private ren: Renderer) {
    }
    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
        this.highlight('200');
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
        this.highlight('30');
    }

    private highlight(width: string) {
        this.ren.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'width', width);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using directives? you can handle them using events itself. Have a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542782/get-the-width-height-and-offset-of-clicked-div-angular-2/42601330#42601330)

Comment: just wanted to handle things using angular2

Comment: In what way is that answer different>