# Add and Remove class in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-class

I want to add background color to the li element when clicked but when I clicked another li element the previous li element background color remains unchanged.

**component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-3 categories">
  <h3>News By Type</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="cat" id="cat_{{i}}" *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index" (click)="sortNewsItems($event,category,i)"><img src="../assets/images/news.jpg" width="70"><h4>{{category}}</h4></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
sortNewsItems(event,cat,index) {
  event.target.classList.add('cat_active');
}
```

Comment: make use of `[ngClass]`

Comment: I already used but It was not worked. that's why i shifted to this.

Comment: give a demo example about `ngClass` which is similar to this

Comment: You will find plenty on internet. But can you share whatever you have tried with `ngClass`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `srcElement` of the `$event`

```
sortNewsItems(event,cat,index) {
  event.srcElement.classList.add('cat_active');
}
```

Read this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542782/get-the-width-height-and-offset-of-clicked-div-angular-2/42601330#42601330)** and use its demo

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the demo in the other answer?. What error you are getting

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but just in case. when there are several classes already on the element you might just want to add or remove an extra class you can do this:

On the element:

```
<div #element </div>
```

On the component.ts

```
@ViewChild('element') element: ElementRef;
```

then you can just add classes or remove them by

```
this.element.nativeElement.classList.add("newclass");
this.element.nativeElement.classList.remove("newclass");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'cat_active' class from all the sibling elements before adding a new 'cat_active' class to the selected element.

**component.html**

```
<li #li class="cat" *ngFor="let category of categories;" (click)="sortNewsItems($event)">
```

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChildren('li') livs: QueryList<any>;

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

sortNewsItems(event) {
    this.livs.forEach(liv => liv.nativeElement.children[0].classList = []);
    event.target.classList.add('cat_active');
}
```

I hope it might helps.

Comment: you can't override all the classes. need a way to remove only `cat_active`

Comment: @Brachi I used ...classList.remove('cat_active').

Comment: The answer worked for me in 2020. I added the template reference variable (the "#li" in the html) manually to several components, so I didnt need the ".children[0]"-part.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngStyle instead of direct class binding in html element.

**component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-3 categories">
  <h3>News By Type</h3>
  <ul>
    <li [ngStyle]="setListItemStyle(category)" class="cat" id="cat_{{i}}" *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index" (click)="sortNewsItems($event,category,i)"><img src="../assets/images/news.jpg" width="70"><h4>{{category.label}}</h4></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
  activeListItem: any = null;
  categories: any[] = [{ id: 1, label: 'Test label 1' }, { id: 2, label: 'Test label 2' }];

  sortNewsItems(event, category, i) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.activeListItem = category;
  }

  setListItemStyle(category) {
    return { 'background-color': this.activeListItem && this.activeListItem.id == category.id ? '#fff000' : null };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just taken a variable and set category name to it when clicked on category li and add active class based on the below condition. finally I set it like what i want. Thank you everyone for the well support.

**component.html**

```
<li class="cat" *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index" (click)="sortNewsItems(category,i)" [ngClass]="{'cat_active':toggleClass === category}"><img src="../assets/images/news.jpg" width="70"><h4>{{category}}</h4></li>
```

**component.ts**

```
toggleClass:string;

sortNewsItems(cat,index) {
  this.toggleClass = cat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read that using srcElement is not a "so good" practice. Better to use renderer2.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(".menu-open-btn a").onclick = function addNewClass() {
    document.querySelector(".mobile-header").classList.add("newClass");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<any-element [ngClass]="{selected: isSelected}">
...
</any-element>
```

OR

```
<any-element [ngClass]="{selected: isSelected, disabled: isDisabled}">
...
</any-element>
```