# Always get a certain DIV, even if the children div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I have a div called box, within inside another div called container.

When the div box is clicked I always get its own ID and everything is perfect, but when the container div is clicked, I want to get the box's id and not the container.

How can I manage it?
I'm new in web developing, thanks for any help!

P.S. I'm coding most in Angular, and if it really needed in JQuery

The code is 1000+ rows...

The main code I'm talking about is:

```
<div id='box' style='width:200px; height:300px;'>
 <div id='container'> A table or some text </div>
</div>
```

When one of the two divs are clicked, after getting the position of the click, I get the element's id by position, but sometimes I get the id "box" and other times I get the id "container". 
The point is that I always want to get the "box" id, and never the container, even if the container has been clicked, I want to get the id of the box that contain that "container"

Hope it's clear..

Comment: Where is your codes ?

Comment: Please provide your code here.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: You want to get the box's ID when the user clicks *outside* the box, but inside the container?  That doesn't seem reasonable (and is in conflict with the question title, which suggests it's the other way around.)  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: @SureshAtta Here it is thank you!

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay here it is!

Comment: @DoubleU23 here it is!

Comment: @DanielBeck hope it's clear now..

Comment: This is only half the code; where is your javascript?   (You might consider changing your classnames to something more sensible, usually "container" means "the thing that contains other things", not "the innermost element").  This should be trivially solvable by simply putting the click event on the "box" element and not on the contained "container", but perhaps there's something more to this that we'd be able to see if you provided your code.

Comment: You need to get the parent...

Comment: Use the logic from this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429689/change-another-divs-background-color-on-click-of-div-with-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

I think what your referring to is event bubbling, take a look at the example on the razden link which will have a fully working example (very clear and simple one)

Here is some further detailed explaination on how it works:
http://www.radzen.com/blog/angular-event-bubbling/

If the below was wrapped in a component

```
`<div><button>click me</button></div>`
```

Then you could add a click handler to it in order to perform a specific task of your liking.