# Apply CSS class only to the button that was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to apply a CSS class only to the button that was clicked (to set it active).

Here's my code:

filter.component.html

```
<div class="button-container">
    <button class="rules" [class.active]="active" (click)="toggleActive()" type="button">Rules</button>
    <button class="dailies" [class.active]="active" (click)="toggleActive()" type="button">Dailies</button>
    <button class="emotions" [class.active]="active" (click)="toggleActive()" type="button">Emotions</button>
</div>
```

filter.component.ts

```
export class FilterComponent {
    active: boolean = false;

    toggleActive(): void {
      this.active = !this.active;
    } 
  constructor() {}
}
```

My problem is, the class gets applied to all 3 buttons. And the active class looks different on each of the buttons. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429689/change-another-divs-background-color-on-click-of-div-with-angular2)

Comment: The class attribute is part of HTML, not CSS. There is no such thing as a CSS class. (CSS has class selectors, but not classes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way :

> Template side :

```
<div class="button-container">
    <button class="rules" [class.active]="active.rules" (click)="toggleActive('rules')" type="button">Rules</button>
    <button class="dailies" [class.active]="active.dailies" (click)="toggleActive('dailies')" type="button">Dailies</button>
    <button class="emotions" [class.active]="active.emotions" (click)="toggleActive('emotions')" type="button">Emotions</button>
</div>
```

> Component side :

```
active = {};

toggleActive(el): void {
    this.active[el] = this.active[el] ? false : true;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-active-toggle)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using an event to get the current clicked element as follows:

```
toggleActive($event) {
   var element = $event.target;
   element.active = !element.active;
};
```

Comment: That works for the toggle, but now I get the following error for the filter.component.html:  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined