# Adding the active class to each clicked button, Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

**I have:**

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons" [ngClass]="{'active': isClicked}" (click)="isClicked = !isClicked"
```

**Result:**

10x button on screen.

When I click on the button number 1:
Each button will get class ".active"

**But I would like:**

When I click **button** number **1**: will get class **".active".**

When I click **button** number **3**: will get class "**.active".**

When I click **button** number **6**: will get class **".active".**

**Result:**

**Button 1**, **Button 3**, **Button 6** - Each this buttons will get class ".active"

How to do that?

PLUNKER: https://plnkr.co/edit/lX3DjN46STmo6gfBkPCc?p=preview

Comment: Here: https://plnkr.co/edit/lX3DjN46STmo6gfBkPCc?p=preview

Comment: A similar answer can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429689/change-another-divs-background-color-on-click-of-div-with-angular2/42429863#42429863)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just maintain a temporary array

```
<button *ngFor="let button of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active':isClicked[i]}" (click)="isClicked[i] = (isClicked[i]? false :true )">button</button>
```

in component  `public isClicked = [];`

working fiddler --> https://plnkr.co/edit/MwuWhtBPPQUQCG2Y9qmx?p=preview

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 3):

When you use `(click)="isClicked = !isClicked"`, you set a *single* `isClicked` property on the component that is used by *all* buttons. Instead, expand your `buttons` array to an array of objects:

```
buttons = [
    { text: 'item1', isClicked: false },
    { text: 'item2', isClicked: false },
    { text: 'item3', isClicked: false },
    // ...
]
```

With this, each button has its own `isClicked` property, which you can use like this:

```html
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons" [ngClass]="{'active': button.isClicked}" (click)="button.isClicked = !button.isClicked">
    {{ button.text }}
</button>
```

[Here's an updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EJagQFQun4nDGMhHD4w5?p=preview).