# How to apply CSS to button dynamically in Angular 7

Tags: css, angular

I'm very new to Angular.

I want to apply CSS (active class) to a button dynamically when it is clicked and the button is not active and need to remove the active class to the button.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="tab">
  <button (click)="onTabClick('0')">Sports</button>
  <button (click)="onTabClick('1')">News</button>
  <button (click)="onTabClick('2')">Movies</button>
</div>
<div>
  <app-sports  *ngIf="tabIndex == 0"></app-sports>
  <app-movies  *ngIf="tabIndex == 2"></app-movies>
</div>
```

**TS file**

tabIndex = 2 ;

```
onTabClick(index){
        this.tabIndex = index;
   }
```

**CSS**

```
    /* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
 .tab button {
   background-color: inherit;
   float: left;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   transition: 0.3s;
 }

 /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
 .tab button:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
 }

 /* Create an active/current tablink class */
 .tab button.active {
   background-color: #ccc;
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding the active class to each clicked button, Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752719/adding-the-active-class-to-each-clicked-button-angular-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **ngClass**
Example
[ngClass]="{'show': tabIndex === 2}"

Here the implemented code for the above scenario

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="tab">
    <button [ngClass]="{'active': tabIndex === 0}" (click)="onTabClick(0)">Transmit</button>
    <button [ngClass]="{'active': tabIndex === 1}" (click)="onTabClick(1)">Published</button>
    <button [ngClass]="{'active': tabIndex === 2}" (click)="onTabClick(2)">Bulk Transmit</button>
</div>
```

**TS FILE**

```
tabIndex = 0;
onTabClick(index){
    this.tabIndex = index;
}
```

**CSS FILE**

```
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a bool variable to toggle

```
// public clicked = false;

<a (click)="clicked ? clicked = false : clicked = true;" [class.active]="clicked">organize</a>
// or shorter
<a (click)="clicked = !clicked" [class.active]="clicked">anchor text</a>
```

The HTML only way

```
<li *ngFor="let n of list" [class.active]="clicked === n" 
     (click)="clicked = n">
   <a>{{n}}</a>
</li>
```

Another way for dynamic verions:

```
// component
toggleReply: any = {};

// view
<a (click)='toggleReply[i] = !toggleReply[i]'>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!toggleReply[i]">reply</ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="toggleReply[i]">close</ng-container>
</a>
```

Comment: Oh you want dynamic template only variables? No var in controller? Your code example includes that. I've updated my answer to include dynamic template-only toggling.